# A website linking to most major math journals?

Tags: journals, soft-question

What's your usual action online in order to browse math journals? Like check Arxiv or MathSciNet. Any other good link directs you to most updated articles in major math journals. Or the traditional way of browsing periodical section of your library is still a better way to get a glimpse of current development in math.

Comment: Could you make it clear which part of this is actually a question, please? More question marks might help!  For instance, "Or the traditional way of browsing periodical section of your library is still a better way to get a glimpse of current development in math." reads like a statement, although I *think* it's intended as a question.

Comment: Closed per Henry's question. Please rewrite, flag for moderator attention, and I'll reopen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The AMS Digital Mathematics Registry has a huge list at http://www.ams.org/dmr/JournalList.html

Answer (score 2):

1. Google.
2. Regensburg library search: http://rzblx1.uni-regensburg.de/ezeit/search.phtml?bibid=AAAAA&colors=7&lang=en
3. Dave Benson's list: http://www.maths.abdn.ac.uk/~bensondj/html/maths.html
4. Google.

Comment: Did I mention Google? :)

Answer (score 0):

As a slight variation on the "Google" answer, [Google Scholar](http://scholar.google.com/) sometimes actually works better. For some searches, the results found by Scholar will be surfaced to the ordinary google.com search results, but this doesn't always work as well as it should so it's best to explicitly try the Scholar version as well.